# Unit Test MyBatis and local variables

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, mybatis

I have a method:

```
public String setBook(Book book) throws LibraryException {
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("author", book.getAuthor());
    params.put("title", book.getTitle());
    //This is MyBatis mapper that returns a response from the database about the success or failure of the save
    mapper.setBook(params);
    int resultCode = (int)params.get("result_code");
    String resultMessage = (String)params.get("result_message");
    if (resultCode != 0) {
        throw new LibraryException (resultCode, resultMessage);
    }
    return resultMessage;
}
```

I want to write unit tests for this method, but I did not understand how to do it if there is a local variable of the hashmap type in the method, which is also filled in by mybatis mapper, who executed the stored procedure in the database. As I understand it, you can't mute a local variable. How can I write a unit test for this method?

Comment: you check whether or not that Mybatis mapper is called with the param you expect to be called, you check the resultMessage, you verify no libraryException is thrown, ... have mybatis throw an exception, check that result